# Create session variable from html form input data

Tags: php, html

I have a form on page `a.php` with `php` code which should set the data from the form into `php` session variables, however i am having trouble making it work. I have **session_start();** at the beginning of every page i want to do this, but its at the top of the `html` so that is why its not in this piece.

Here is the code:

```
<form class="form1" method="post" action="" id="form1">
    <div class="form-group add_to_cart_prompt">
        <span class="">Add something to cart</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="sticker" class="form_sticker_name" value="something">
        <label class="quantity_desc" for="quantity" title="how much?">Quantity</label>
        <input class="btn btn-default quantity_input" type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="how much ?" min="0" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group bottom_buttons">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default add_yes">Add to cart</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default add_no">Close</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

`PHP` which is executing the form is on the same page as the form:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
       if (isset($_POST['sticker'])) {
            $sticker_name = $_POST['sticker'];
            $_SESSION['sess_sticker'] = $sticker_name;
        }
    }
?>
```

I can set session variables to some `string`, and that works ok, but when i try to put data from the form it gives me this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: sticker in
>   B:\Programs\xampp\htdocs\D2S\shopping_cart.php on line 99

I have looked up how to fix the error, and have been trying a lot and can't fix it. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: that error catches by the `isset` i am not sure if do you have any other call for the `sticker` field other than that on the same page. however, please add a condition `!empty($_POST['sticker'])` on the second condition.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, a variable or array element which has never been set is different from one whose value is null; attempting to access such an unset value is a runtime error.

That's what you're running into: the array $_POST does not have any element at the index "sticker", so the interpreter aborts your program before it ever gets to the nullity test.

You can test for the existence of a variable or array element without actually trying to access it; that's what the special operator isset does:

```
if (isset($_POST['sticker'])) {
   //do something
}
```

Also I have tested your form code on my machine, and it seemed to be working fine and session variable was set using form data.

Comment: did you call the session variable from the same page or another page? I have been trying to display it on another page

Comment: from the same page Backo Backic

Comment: and how would i acces it on some other page?

Comment: ADD in action the name of the php file like
<form class="form1" method="post" action="test.php" id="form1">

NEXT write the php code in test.php file

Comment: added the link to the page in action atribute, and pasted this code in the page

<?php
          if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            if (isset($_POST['sticker']) && !empty($_POST['sticker'])) {
              $sticker_name = $_POST['sticker'];
              $_SESSION['sess_sticker'] = $sticker_name;
            }
          }
          echo $_SESSION['sess_sticker'];
          ?> 

but it is now empty?

Comment: can you try this in your new page:

<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['sticker'])) {
        $sticker_name = $_POST['sticker'];
        $_SESSION['sess_sticker'] = $sticker_name;
    }
}

var_dump($_SESSION);
?>

Comment: result:

array(2) { ["session_shopping_cart"]=> array(0) { } ["sess_sticker"]=> NULL } 


why is it null instead of 'something' (thats the value of the input with name="sticker")?

Comment: please compare session ids.

The solution might be as simple as your browser not accepting session cookies.

You retrieve the session id by calling session_id(). Do that right after session_start() it should give you a constant value if the session is the same. Otherwise for every request a new session is instantiated.

Comment: sublime texxt 3

Comment: when moving to different pages are you changing directories? or are your files all in same directory?

Comment: they are in the same directory